# I am not very experienced and am trying to handle collisions in my hash table. However

Tags: java, arrays, hash, collision, string-hashing

I am not very experienced and am trying to handle collisions in my hash table. However, it just skips over it and doesn't write it at all. I figured the while loop with the conditional if would take care of it... I have been playing around with it for a while now and feel like I am mixing everything up or losing my mind.

```
    File file = new File("info.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            temp = nhash.hashing(line,maxSize);
            System.out.println(line + " " + " Hash key: " + temp);

            int loc = (int)temp;
            if(arr[loc] != null)       // I FIGURED THIS WOULD SOLVE it
            {                          // THE ISSUE... But IT DOESN'T
                while(arr[loc] != null) {
              //  System.out.println("Collision at [" + loc + "] with Data Item : [" + arr[loc] + "]");
                    loc++;
                    if(loc == maxSize)
                        loc = 0;
                }
            }else {
                arr[loc] = line;
             //   System.out.println("Data Item[" + line + "] Stored in index [" + loc + "] of array.");
                key[j] = loc;
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Remove the `else` and braces. You have to set the data anyway even a collision occur or not.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it =). So it was doing (one or the other) but not both.